# a way to read from the reverse order and ignore a specific amount of characters

Tags: c, file-handling, stdio

I want a program in C to read from a file from a specific portion in reverse order, ignoring a specific number of characters from being printed. For example:

`hello world`

I want to start reading from `world` but I want to ignore the first 3 characters and only print `wo`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHARACTER -1

int main(){
    FILE *file = fopen("temp.txt", "r");

    fseek(file, -3, SEEK_END);
    char print ;
    fseek(file, print = CHARACTER, SEEK_CUR);


    char buffer[615];
    fscanf(file, "%s", buffer);
    printf("%c", print);
}
```

Comment: Seek to the very end. Seek "forward" (`-1` from the current position) and read one character. If it's not a space, discard the character and seek to the previous character (you now need to seek `-2` from the current position). If you find the space, read exactly two characters into a buffer, null-terminate the buffer, and print it.

Comment: no i said i want to read from the reverse order means :

```hello world```

i want to read from ``world`` and ignore the first ``3`` characters means i want to get only ``wo``

Comment: Then just seek to the end. Seek back five bytes. Read two bytes (with `fread`, or `fscanf` format `"%2s"`). That's it.

Comment: By the way, note that `fseek` does *not* know about newline-variants and their translations. On Windows the newline is *two* characters, but when you read from a text-file it will be translated into a single character.

Comment: it doesn't work if i seek 3 bytes and then seek 2 bytes from the current position i get ``world``

Comment: `fscanf("%2s", buffer)` reads 2 "letters" and adds a `'\0'` to buffer ... not proper C: `seek(-5); scanf("%2s")` ... also pay attention to common final newlines in files

Comment: that way workes

Comment: the problem has been solved

Comment: Just one more **important** thing... this does not feel like a solution, it feels like a [kludge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge): it works for the very specific situation you care about right now, it will not work in the real world general case